# KB4093120 update for windows server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016

Is the KB4093120 update availlable for Windows Server 2012 R2? Or is this update only available for Windows Server 2016 + Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

KB4093120 is a cumulative update for Windows 2016 Server and Windows 10 LTSB. It does not exist for Windows 2012 R2.

The exact updated files are [these](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/A/F/2AF74720-FCAE-4A53-BA1D-B1DEA2136AD1/4093120.csv).

The update modules in KB4093120 are applied on Windows 2012 R2 in different packages (separate KBs or cumulative updates).